# handle browser back button event in angular when route is not changed

Tags: angularjs, routeparams

I have a button inside a project which redirects to another project, which means that it changes only the route param, not the route itself.
How do I handle browser back button in this cas?

Comment: can u share the code for clarification?

Comment: Not sure in angular but core js window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {history.pushState(null, document.title, {{PATH}});});